What is the Expression for Reconstruction After Derivative Sampling?
I've been trying to use Equation (1) in Linden and Abramson to reconstruct a signal using uniformly spaced samples of the signal and its first and second derivatives. The reconstruction seems to work fine using samples of the signal, and samples of the signal and its first derivative. However, I can't get it to work when using samples of the signal and its first and second derivatives.
The signal in question is:
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc}
x(t) = \frac{{\sinc\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}^4}{4}
$$
which has a Fourier transform $X(f)$ that satisfies $X(f) = 0$ for $|f| >= 1$.
Is (1) in the cited reference the correct formula to use for this problem?
Edit: Adding code to illustrate the problem, borrowing from original Answer by @Stephen
% sampling period
R = 2; W = 1; tau = (R+1)/(2*W);

% sample times
kmax = round(10/tau);
k    = -kmax:kmax;
kT   = k*tau;

% samples of signal x[k] = x(k*tau)
x = sinc(kT/2).^4/4;

% samples of first derivative dx/dt
dxdt = sinc(kT/2).^3.*(pi*kT.*cos(pi*kT/2)-2*sin(pi*kT/2))/pi./kT.^2;
dxdt(k==0) = 0;

% sample of second derivative d2x/dt2
d2xdt2 = sinc(kT/2).^2.*(pi^2*kT.^2+2*(pi^2*kT.^2-5).*cos(pi*kT)-8*pi*kT.*sin(pi*kT)+10)./pi^2./kT.^4;
d2xdt2(k == 0) = -pi^2/12;   

% interpolation to reconstruct xr(t), equation (1) from Linden and Abramson
tt = linspace(-10,10,101)';  % interpolation times (change as desired)
xr = nan(size(tt));
for idx = 1:numel(tt)
    w = sinc((tt(idx) - kT)/tau).^(R+1);
    xr(idx) = sum((x + (tt(idx) - kT).*dxdt + (tt(idx) - kT).^2/2.*d2xdt2).*w); %/sum(w);
end

% true signal x(t)
xtrue = sinc(tt/2).^4/4;

figure
plot(tt,xtrue,tt,xr,kT,x,'o');
legend('x(t)','xr(t)','x(kT)')



I have completely rewritten this answer as I have discovered that the expression published by Linden & Abramson (1960) is incorrect, which they subsequently published a correction for in the following errata:
Linden, D. A., & Abramson, N. M. (1960). A generalization of the sampling theorem. Information and Control, 3(1), 26-31. Errata, Ibid. 4 (1961), 95-96.
Moreover, I have found that the corrected expression is incorrectly transcribed in several other publications, for example Higgens (1985) and Jerri (1977).
Here is revised Matlab code for $R=2$ that implements the corrected expression that appears in the errata, which now obtains the expected results (see figure below):
R = 2;
W = 1;  % bandwidth of sinc(t/2) is 1/4, so sinc(t/2)^4 is 1

% sample interval and times: change as desired ensuring tau <= (R+1)/(2*W)
tau = (R+1)/(2*W);  % sample interval
t = (-10:10)'*tau;  % sample times

% signal, x[t]
x = sinc(t/2).^4/4;

% signal first derivative, dx/dt
dxdt = (cos(pi*t/2) - sinc(t/2)).*sinc(t/2).^3./t;
dxdt(t==0) = 0;

% signal second derivative, d2x/dt2
d2xdt2 = sinc(t/2).^2.*(pi^2*t.^2+2*(pi^2*t.^2-5).*cos(pi*t)-8*pi*t.*sin(pi*t)+10)./pi^2./t.^4;
d2xdt2(t==0) = -pi^2/12;

% interpolation
tt = linspace(min(t),max(t),101)';         % interpolation times (change as desired)
xx = zeros(size(tt));
for idx = 1:numel(tt)    
    w = sinc((tt(idx)-t)/tau).^(R+1);
    switch R
        case 0
            xx(idx) = sum(x.*w);
        case 1
            xx(idx) = sum((x + (tt(idx) - t).*dxdt).*w);
        case 2
            xx(idx) = sum((x + (tt(idx) - t).*dxdt + (tt(idx) - t).^2/2.*((pi/tau)^2*(R+1)/3*x + d2xdt2)).*w);
    end
end

xx_exact = sinc(tt/2).^4/4;
plot(tt,xx_exact,'.-', tt,xx,'.', t,x,'k.');
legend({'exact','interpolated','sampled data'})

The above Matlab code produces the following figure where the exact and interpolated data appear visually indistinguishable:


I'm not following. The code starts with computing x, which I think represents x(t). The variable tau means something different than in the linked paper, where tau is the sampling period (R+1)/(2W), and W is the bandwidth of the signal (W = 1). Then the for loop computes uniformly spaced samples x[n*T] where T = 0.2, based on "truth" x(t), dx(t)/dt, and d2x(t)/dt2. I thought the idea is to start with uniformly spaced samples of x(t), dx(t)/dt, and d2x(t)/dt2 with a sampling period of tau = (R+1)/(2W) and then reconstruct x(t) at arbitrary times (the t vector) from those samples.

Yes, $x$ is your signal. In the paper, $\tau$ is just the sample interval. It's not written clearly in their paper, but really their equation for it is stating the maximum sample interval that theoretically permits perfect reconstruction of the continuous signal. Adjust the sample times and interpolation times in my code as you see fit (I used a variety of values just to investigate the problems, and those you see are the remnants).

should we delete the two preceding comments (and this comment) as they are no longer coherent with the completely rewritten answer?

Excellent!  I don't know how I didn't find that Errata paper when I had been searching on this topic. Thanks for taking the time to find it and post your answer.
